# Modifying SKUniform of SKShader

Tags: macos, cocoa, sprite-kit, glsl

I'm trying to make a simple fractal renderer using Sprite Kit. The fractal is computed using "Shader3.fsh". So far its working OK but I now want to be able to click on the window and have the fractal recenter to the clicked area. The way I was planning on doing this was computing a translation matrix based on the mouse click and then handing that off as an SKUniform to the shader. Within the shader I then multiply `vec2(v_tex_coord.x,v_tex_coord.y, 1.0)` by this translation matrix. How can I get this new matrix into the shader? Also, I would like to be able to magnify using the "pinch-to-zoom" gesture on the trackpad but 
`- (void)magnifyWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event`
isn't being called.
Here is the relevant code

`

```
#import "GameScene.h"
#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>

@implementation GameScene
{
    GLKMatrix3 transMatrix;
}
@synthesize myShader, scalingMatrixUniform, transMatrixUniform;

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {

    /* Here we set up the matrix to give us the appropriate window */
    GLKMatrix3 scalingMatrix = GLKMatrix3Make(3.0, 0.0, 0.0,    //reduces the scale by a third
                                              0.0, 3.0, 0.0,
                                              0.0, 0.0, 3.0);
    transMatrix = GLKMatrix3Make(1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                                 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
                                 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);


    scalingMatrixUniform = [SKUniform uniformWithName:@"scalingMatrix" floatMatrix3:scalingMatrix];
    transMatrixUniform = [SKUniform uniformWithName:@"transMatrix" floatMatrix3:transMatrix];
    myShader = [SKShader shaderWithFileNamed:@"Shader3.fsh"];

    //We then hand off the transformation matrix to the shader as uniform data
    [myShader addUniform: scalingMatrixUniform];
    [myShader addUniform: transMatrixUniform];

    //we create a rectangle sprite which wille be shaded with our custom shader
    SKSpriteNode *mySprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[NSColor redColor]
                                                          size:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    mySprite.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

    //We hand off the shader to the sprite
    mySprite.shader = myShader;

    //We add the shaded sprite to the view
    [self addChild:mySprite];
}

-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

    CGFloat mouseX = [theEvent locationInNode:self].x;
    CGFloat mouseY = [theEvent locationInNode:self].y;
    mouseX = mouseX / [self size].width;
    mouseY = mouseY / [self size].height;
    transMatrix = GLKMatrix3Make(1.0, 0.0, -mouseX,
                                 0.0, 1.0, -mouseY,
                                 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}


-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}

@end
```

`